# Is it possible to create a new directory using code in mac os x app programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to store log files as xml in mac ox x application. So i need to create a directory for every date, then in the created directory i want to store my xml file name with current time.

Eg : Documents/**01-10-2013**/09:09:23.xml.

How do i create directory like above and name the directory by date and time?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Type `man 2 mkdir` into a terminnal window.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/). That does what you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's Documentation [**NSFileManager**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

1) `createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`

**Creates a directory with the given attributes at the specified URL.**

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

*Parameters*

**url**

A file `URL` that specifies the directory to create. If you want to specify a relative path, you must set the current working directory before creating the corresponding `NSURL` object. This parameter must not be `nil`.

**createIntermediates**

If `YES`, this method creates any non-existent parent directories as part of creating the directory in url. If `NO`, this method fails if any of the intermediate parent directories does not exist.

**attributes**

The file attributes for the new directory. You can set the owner and group numbers, file permissions, and modification date. If you specify nil for this parameter, the directory is created according to the umask(2) Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page of the process. The “Constants” section lists the global constants used as keys in the attributes dictionary. Some of the keys, such as `NSFileHFSCreatorCode` and `NSFileHFSTypeCode`, do not apply to directories.

**error**

On input, a pointer to an error object. If an error occurs, this pointer is set to an actual error object containing the error information. You may specify `nil` for this parameter if you do not want the error information.

*Return Value*
`YES` if the directory was created, `YES` if createIntermediates is set and the directory already exists), or `NO` if an error occurred.

2) To get the current system time:[**Date Formatters**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

```
NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];//Change the format as per your requirement.
NSString *newDateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", newDateString);
```

Hope it helps...Happy coding...